# Should I use 'IdentityUser' when I implement an authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I was working on implementing username and password authentication.

We didn't use any authentication templates.

And I thought `IdentityUser` has a lot of columnn.

Username, password, nickname are enough columns for us.

Old Method. Login API has logged user information in session.

And other controllers use it.

But I'm not sure It's right way or not in .NET Core Web dev.

Should I use `IdentityUser`? or Was that method I implemented okay?

Comment: To take advantage of things like reset password, forgot password, login attempts, lockedout etc you need at least a few columns. Also you might need a salt and hash columns.  I usually create my own class/table with the fields that work for me but there is a minimum depending on what you want.

Comment: If your application is behind the corporate firewall, then yes you can use IdentityUser method. I would recommend to change or customized it to some degree. If you are developing application which is facing internet then please do more research and try to avoid standard or default Identity User method. There are many alternatives to it available.

Answer (score 1):

I have been developing in .Net for nearly 20 years and I still ask my self the same question. There is always the "latest and greatest" being hyped by Microsoft and other talking heads and honestly, 99% of the time what is being pushed as the "right" and "correct" thing to do is no longer "right and correct" after a few years pass.

If you asking about how you should do it in ".net core" then using the `IdentityUser` interface is the way to go because WHEN (not if but WHEN) Microsoft decides to scrap .NET Core (everyone can pounce on me all they want) for backward compatibility purposes they will "LIKELY" continue use of the interface.

However, Even if they do it might be 1 or 3 or 5 years until Microsoft says, NOPE! That's legacy you need to redo it.

So my answer is, without knowing all the facts, is if you have a custom implementation that suites your needs then stick with it. You aren't going to forced to change it in a few years because Microsoft decided the latest hottest open fad is the way everyone should be doing thing.

Comment: .net 5 is .net core. But aspx web forms still exist. So I don't know why you think .net core will ever be scrapped.

Comment: I tried to follow "standard" way. It wasn't easy in .NET for beginners. I searched for it but the documents are lack. anyway. Thanks for your answer. you helped a lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought IdentityUser has a lot of columnn. Username, password, nickname are enough columns for us.

Please note that the most of properties of `IdentityUser` in ASP.NET Core Identity system are required for user management.

> I was working on implementing username and password authentication.

If you just want to implement and integrate simple authentication and authorization mechanism in your ASP.NET Core MVC app, you can try to implement and use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I should search more for it. Login page is a razor page. and other pages implemented as a React app. I don't know how to integrate them yet.